# How to resolve "Path variable is not sanitized using getCanonicalPath()" SonarQube Issue?

Tags: java, sonarqube, filepath

I am trying to validate API Response with Json Schema File.

code snippet:

```
File schemaFile = new File("file\name\in\String\format");
    isTrue("String message", JSONValidationUtil.isJsonValid(schemaFile, responseBody.asString()));
```

`JsonValdationUtil` is custom class written which contain methods for schema validation, and responseBody(RestAssured) is my response object after hitting rest api.
My code is integrated with sonarQube server and once I commit my code I am getting below error from sonarqube.

> Path variable is not sanitized using getCanonicalPath()

I used file.getCanonicalPath() and file.getCanonicalFile() methods to sanitize my file path, But still I am getting same error.

Comment: you need to show the exact code where you get that issue from sonarqube. I don't think from the code you pasted the error occurs

Comment: Where is your ***Path variable*** ?

Comment: Path variable is with in the project structure under a schema folder.